# Starts landscape orientation in iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, orientation, landscape

I have to tried iPad application for landscape orientation so do some changes in info.plist are

[image]
AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    NSLog(@"screenBound:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(screenBound));

    return YES;
}
```

Then i get the screen resolution from CGRect is screenBound:{{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}
But i want {{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}, How to do this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your .plist instead `UIInterfaceOrientation` use `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`, and make landscape orientaation the first one in UISupportedInterfaceOrientations list.

Answer (score 0):

Place this line code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be help:
Write in this method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```